# How to insert input with several values in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a little rental project where I basically currently have a table which shows 5 types of values which are taken from a database (mySQL) and are shown with the help of twig.
A MVC structure is applied.
Visual representation:
[image]

Sorry, I blocked the information out because the addresses and whatnot are actually real.

And now to the issue:
I'd like to be able to add a customer (and later on edit and remove as well, but first things first.)

I put this in my CustomerModel.php file:

```
class CustomerModel extends AbstractModel {
  public function addCustomer($customerNumber, $customerName, $customerAddress, $postalAddress, $phoneNumber) {
    $customersQuery = "INSERT INTO Customers(customerNumber, customerName, customerAddress, postalAddress, phoneNumber) " .
                      "VALUES(:customerNumber, :customerName, :customerAddress, :postalAddress, :phoneNumber)";
    $customersStatement = $this->db->prepare($customersQuery);
    $customersStatement->execute(["customerNumber" => $customerNumber,
    "customerName" => $customerName,
    "customerAddress" => $customerAddress,
    "postalAddress" => $postalAddress,
    "phoneNumber" => $phoneNumber]);
    if (!$customersStatement) die("Fatal error.");
    $customerNumber = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    return $customerNumber;
  }
```

and this in CustomerController.php

```
class CustomerController extends AbstractController {
  public function addCustomer() {
    return $this->render("AddCustomer.twig", []);
  }

  public function customerAdded() {
    $form = $this->request->getForm();
    $customerName = $form["customerName"];
    $customerModel = new CustomerModel($this->db);
    // $customerNumber = $customerModel->addCustomer($customerNumber, $customerName, $customerAddress, $postalAddress, $phoneNumber);
    $customerNumber = $customerModel->addCustomer($customerName);
    $customerAddress = $customerModel->addCustomer($customerName);
    $postalAddress = $customerModel->addCustomer($customerName);
    $phoneNumber = $customerModel->addCustomer($customerName);
    $properties = ["customerNumber" => $customerNumber,
                   "customerName" => $customerName,
                  "customerAddress" => $customerAddress,
                "postalAddress" => $postalAddress,
              "phoneNumber" => $phoneNumber];
    return $this->render("CustomerAdded.twig", $properties);
  }   
}
```

and now when I try to enter the information in my form, I get the errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function Carrental\Models\CustomerModel::addCustomer(), 1 passed in
>   /home/vagrant/code/assignments/XXXX/src/Controllers/CustomerController.php
>   on line 18 and exactly 5 expected in
>   /home/vagrant/code/assignments/XXXX/src/Models/CustomerModel.php on
>   line 11
>
> ( ! ) ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>   Carrental\Models\CustomerModel::addCustomer(), 1 passed in
>   /home/vagrant/code/assignments/XXXX/src/Controllers/CustomerController.php
>   on line 18 and exactly 5 expected in
>   /home/vagrant/code/assignments/XXXX/src/Models/CustomerModel.php on
>   line 11

Clearly, there is something I definitely don't understand with what I have done..

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That message seems quite clear, your method expects 5 parameters, you only gave it one. And always the same, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `public function addCustomer($customerNumber, $customerName, $customerAddress, $postalAddress, $phoneNumber)` expects exactly 5 parameters, but you call it with only one (and it's always the same). Change your `customerAdded()` to something like this (make sure the `$form["XYZ"]` fields have the actual names of your form fields):

```
public function customerAdded() {
    $form = $this->request->getForm();
    $customerName = $form["customerName"];
    $customerNumber = $form["customerNumber"];
    $customerAddress = $form["customerAddress"];
    $postalAddress = $form["postalAddress"];
    $phoneNumber = $form["phoneNumber"];
    $customerModel = new CustomerModel($this->db);
    $customerModel->addCustomer($customerNumber, $customerName, $customerAddress, $postalAddress, $phoneNumber);
    $properties = ["customerNumber" => $customerNumber,
                   "customerName" => $customerName,
                  "customerAddress" => $customerAddress,
                "postalAddress" => $postalAddress,
              "phoneNumber" => $phoneNumber];
    return $this->render("CustomerAdded.twig", $properties);
  }
```